# Magento Layout error

Tags: xml, magento, layout

We have a Magento module that works fine in more of 50 stores and was fine also in this particular store... but after update in one of them... is not more loading the templates, the controllers are called, work fine, but the page don't show up, this problem happens only with the module, the other templates of the site, work fine... putting the store to show the erros, this is one clue

**Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Core_Block_Template could not be converted to string**

also we putted a log in  **Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update** and many erros like below show up..

```
2013-09-11T20:54:04+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page could not be converted to string  in /home/toyshow/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 110
2013-09-11T20:54:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Object of class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page to string conversion  in /home/toyshow/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 110
2013-09-11T20:54:04+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page could not be converted to string  in /home/toyshow/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 460
```

Had have somene a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss  to miss an `->toHtml()` at the end of of on of you layout calls

For example

```
$this->getLayout()->someFunction()

change to 

$this->getLayout()->someFunction()->toHtml()
```